# How do I call another Router path from existing Router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this case where in my app.js I want to display components in the whole screen

I am using `react-native-router`

```
<NativeRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomePage} />
    <Route path='/login' render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
    <Route path='/signup' render={props => <Signup {...props} />} />
    <Route path='/appPage' render={props => <AppPage {...props} />} />
    <Route
    path='/formEditor' render={props => <FormEditor {...props} />} />
  </Switch>
</NativeRouter>
```

And I also have a bottomNavigation that is also displayed when logged in, where I display components above.

```
<NativeRouter>
  <Route exact path='/' render={props => <Formbuilder {...props} />} />
    <Route
      path='/formBuilder'
      render={props => <Formbuilder {...props} />}
     />
    <Route path='/stats' render={props => <Stats {...props} />} />
    <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule} />
    <Route path='/Range' render={props => <Range {...props} />} />
    <Route path='/formEditor' render={props => <FormEditor {...props} />} />
</NativeRouter>
 <View>
             ....bottomNavigation code that I always display here
 </View>
```

Now I want to call a component(ex: login) from `FormBuilder` component that is rendered in this Route to display it in full screen, but it only displays the routes that are in this page(bottomNavigation).

Comment: Lacking `switch` for the second one?

Comment: Tried it but no, the second component works fine. But when I try to call a route from `app.js` component doesn't work.